# Удаление часть текста из String (java)

Tags: java, строки, методы

Есть строка String **N** , она имеет какой то текст: *Жили были баб-да деда , была у них внучка Люба, очень красивая*.

Вопрос, как удалить часть текста : *Жили были баб-да деда?*

Comment: @Vyacheslav-Mischenko
думаю данном случае сабстринг не правильный вариант т.к. а что если то что надо удалить (у нас "Жили были баб-да деда") встречается не на одном месте?
и по этому реплейс более правильный вариант.

Comment: Вы наверное хотели сказать с точностью наоборот) Реплейс в данном случае не годен, а вот в сабстринг позиция является ранее определенным значением

Comment: и почему же? что если:
давайте вспомним что нибудь из русских сказок на пример Колобок ) там "Колобок, Колобок, я тебя съем!" встречается многократно, и надо удалить, вопрос как будете удалять с помощью сабстринга?

Comment: @Эникейщик там просто строка читается с 23го индекса/символа до конца. блин пока баллов/репутации не хватит чтоб оставить комменты, по этому и приходится создать новый ответ, сорри )

Comment: так задача не в том что бы удалить значения до определенного символа а удалить само Жили были баб-да деда. Как бы то ни было мне уже хорошо помог ответ Данила)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это делается таким образом (есть исходная строка `source` и строка для удаления `delete`):

```
source = source.replace (delete, "");
```

То есть, по сути, вы просто заменяете строку на пустоту, или, другими словами, удаляете :)

Если надо, вот код готовый код:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ideone
{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String source, delete;
        source = in.nextLine();
        delete = in.nextLine();
        source = source.replace (delete, "");
        System.out.println (source);
    }
}
```

Также вот [ссылочка на Ideone](https://ideone.com/VTgzki).

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно удалить только начало строки и/или конец строки, то можно взять часть строки от символа с номером `startNum` до конца строки , или до определенного символа `endNum`.
Файл "StringDel.java":

```
    /*
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840608/Удаление-часть-текста-из-string-java/840741#840741 
 */
package stringDel;

/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class StringDel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Жили были баб-да деда , была у них внучка Люба, очень красивая.";
        int startNum = 23;
        int endNum = str.length();
        /*оставить только часть текста от startNum до endNum*/
        str = str.substring(startNum, endNum);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
/*
run:
 была у них внучка Люба, очень красивая.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
 */
```

PS. Предыдущий ответ более подходит. Мой ответ можно рассматривать только как частный случай.

Comment: И что откуда удалилось?

Comment: Создается новая строка с тем же именем 'str'. В неё заносится часть строки от символа с номером 'startNum' до символа с номером 'endNum', возвращенная методом 'substring'. В моем случае, удалилось начало строки.